# jquery clone div into variable and remove style attribute

Tags: jquery

I need to remove all style attributes from a variable. I'm trying to use

```
someVar = $(someVar).find("*").removeAttr("style");
```

however this removes most of the code for some reason. It only comes back with 10 lines or so and missing out on the rest. If I do the following

```
someVar = $(someVar).removeAttr("style");
```

it only removes the first style attribute and returns everything else (as expected).

the someVar variable is basically a clone of an existing div

```
var someVar = $('someDiv#someID').clone();
```

edit: just to clarify, I want to remove the style attr from all child elements which are in the someVar variable

edit2: here's a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pscs7ttp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try;

```
$('#element').clone().attr('style', '');
```

This removes style attributes in the clone, not original element. If you want to clean attributes for original element; simply switch *clone* and *attr* calls.

**UPDATE**: If you want remove all style attributes from all child elements, use; (*note the ******)

```
$('#element').removeAttr('style');  // remove style from self  
$('#element *').removeAttr('style'); // remove style from children
```

**with a variable**:

```
var variable = $('#element').clone();
// Remove children styles
variable.find('*').removeAttr('style');
// Remove self style
variable.removeAttr('style');
```

Run the below code to see that all styles are being removed:
*(Taken from @MinusFour's answer and modified)*

```js
$(function(){
  // Clone the element
  var variable = $('#element').clone();
  // Remove children styles
  variable.find('*').removeAttr('style');
  // Remove self style
  variable.removeAttr('style');
  // Output result to see if it works
  $('#result').text(variable.prop('outerHTML'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
<div id="element" style="padding:0;">
  <div style="padding:0;"></div>
  <div style="padding:0;"></div>
  <div style="padding:0;"></div>
  <div style="padding:0;"></div>
  <div style="padding:0;"></div>
  <div style="padding:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but this only removes 1 style attribute. There are about 10 in the cloned div

Comment: So are they like; _style="padding:0;" style="margin:0;" style="color:white;"_ ? Or _style="padding:0;margin:0;color:white;"_ ?

Comment: Or, are the _styles_ you want to remove in child elements?

Comment: style="display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 15px; vertical-align: top. Yes I want to remove styles in all child elements

Comment: So you want to remove styles for the cloned (main) element and all child of elements? Please update the question if so, because it is not clear from the question that what you want is this. Meanwhile, i will post an answer.

Comment: @MQC I have updated the answer, you can see it works as expected.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work as expected when working on a variable. Unless I'm doing something wrong again. I've added a JSFiddle link to the original post

Comment: @MQC I have updated the answer to include a variable. It works with variable too.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(someVar).find("[style]").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("style"));
    })
```

Comment: thanks but when I do console.log($(someVar).html()); it comes back with just 1 line

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each object with each():

```js
$(function(){
  $('#d').find('*').each(function(i, el){
    $(el).removeAttr('style');
    });
  $('#result').text($('#d').html());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
<div id="d">
  <div style ="st"></div>
  <div style ="st"></div>
  <div style ="st"></div>
  <div style ="st"></div>
  <div style ="st"></div>
  <div style ="st"></div>
</div>
```

Just remember that find won't select the parent object (#d).